# iAD on iPAD is transparent but clickable (Monotouch)

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, iad

I am using monotouch 4.0.7 and was able to get iAd to show up sucessfully on iPhone(normal) and iPhone(retina).

It seems that the iPad version is loaded successfully, clickable but it's completely empty. In the emulator it has the mousedown color too.

I've tried extending the frame of both the view controller and the view to 1024x768 but it's still not showing up.

Is this normal behavior in Portrait mode? I am using ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait.

By the way, AdLoaded is getting called and there are no warnings in application output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the issue, the problem (I'm guessing) is that you're using "ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait" as the identifier in your "RequiredContentSizeIdentifiers" set. The problem is that the string is not the same as the identifier. You should instead use the class properties on ADBannerView which are ADBannerView.SizeIdentifierPortrait or ADBannerView.SizeIdentifierLandscape.

Let me know if this sorts out your issue,

ChrisNTR

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Here is the code:

NSMutableSet nsM = new NSMutableSet();

nsM.Add(new NSString("ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait"));
adBannerView.RequiredContentSizeIdentifiers = nsM;

Comment: You still need the set so it'll look like;

Comment: var contentSizeIndentifiers = new NSMutableSet();
   contentSizeIndentifiers.Add(ADBannerView.SizeIdentifierPortrait);

adView.RequiredContentSizeIdentifiers = contentSizeIndentifiers;

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works great. I've re-uploaded the app to the app store with the fix.